# How to change language/region in a YQL search.spelling/search.suggestion query?

Tags: api, localization, yahoo, spell-checking, yql

I'm trying to use YQL's spelling and search suggestions, but as much as I try I cant find a way to change the language/region for the query, how is this done? I want to look for spelling/suggestions in spanish/mexico (`"es-MX"`)

I'm pretty happy with the results I get for queries in English, but when looking in Spanish I get no results:

```
select * from search.suggest where query="dolor de cabeza"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2010-11-22T17:41:13Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results/>
</query>
```

I've looked around for a way to change `yahoo:lang="en-US"` to `yahoo:lang="es-MX"` but I cant find andy documentation about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far I know you can't. The YQL returns results only in English
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-l18n.html